# Get IP address of submitter

Tags: 7, nodes

I'm actually testing a website with Drupal 7.

I am searching a way to get the visitors' IP, when they submit a new node; the users can also be not logged-in, as anonymous users are allowed to submit new content.

I can't find a module to do that, and I don't know how to use hooks or PHP to achieve this.

What should I do?

Comment: what do you want to do with the visitor IP? Save it somewhere? Render it on the node page or what?

Comment: no, I only need this for some legal stuff ... Just save it in mysql, so I can see "who" write a node (without register).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I haven't found a module which does this yet.  You can do these steps:

1. Create a text field named ip_address
2. Manage display: make the field hidden
3. Use [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) or a custom hook (or even CSS) to hide the field when filling out the form
4. Create a Rule on event "Before saving content"
5. Set a condition of content type: your content type
6. Set a condition of Data comparison: [node:is-new], Data value: True (check the checkbox)
7. Set an action of Set a data value, and set the field to be:

PHP Code

```
<?php
  print ip_address();
?>
```

That should do it.

You could also accomplish this by creating a module and using some hooks

Comment: Work great !
Of course, need PHP module from Core enabled.
Thank you.

Comment: You can also use the [current-user:ip-address] token in the field default, then hide the field as you suggest above.

Comment: One can also use `comment:hostname`, such that the PHP module is not acquired.

Answer (score 4):

There is a simple way to do this. Install the [Computed Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field) module.

Add a computed filed (for IP address) to your content type and add the following line in **Computed Code (PHP)** textarea to get current ip address of the author

```
$entity_field[0]['value'] = ip_address();
```

That's it.You will get submitted author ip address. No need to install any other modules

Answer (score 1):

I wrote simple module for saving author ip address. With this module you can add field to content type, which filled with ip address author on node creation.

https://drupal.org/sandbox/drupaladmin/2191469