# How to show the ip address in revision listing?

Tags: 7

When I see all the revisions of a particular node through in my site, say, `http://www.mysite.com/node/1/revisions`,  I see an html table representing our data having two columns mainly REVISION and OPERATIONS. I have a requirement to add another column called IP Address from where the content originated for tracking purpose. I have already added a field in ip_address in the database, but don't know how to show the ip address in the revision listing? Plz help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using rules and views.
First to create the rule:

> - Create a text field named ip_address
> - Manage display: make the field hidden
> - Use Display Suite or a custom hook (or even CSS) to hide the field when filling out the form
> - Create a Rule on event "Before saving content"
> - Set a condition of content type: your content type
> - Set a condition of Data comparison: [node:is-new], Data value: True (check the checkbox)
> - Set an action of Set a data value, and set the field to be:
> - PHP Code:

```
<?php
  print ip_address();
?>
```

Above taken from here: [Get IP address of submitter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29298/get-ip-address-of-submitter)

For your purposes the 6th bullet (your rule condition) can be set-up like this:
[image]

And for the final action (7th bullet) if you don't want to use the php you can first add and action

> 'Add a variable' -> Value IP Address

and use that as in a second 'set a data value' action...

Now you can create a view that displays in a table format the fields 'Content Title' 'Revision Log' (i'm guessing this is what the operations column is recording?) and 'IP_Address', sorted by 'Node revision ID (desc)', or similar....

As it stands I am aware that this answer might not work for multiple revisions, rather only displays the IP for the latest revision. I imagine that when setting up your initial (hidden) IP_address field if you allow multiple values the rule will simply add values rather than over-write them. Maybe someone else on here has guidance on that...